# How to approach the following TypeScript code for testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, testing

I have been asked to **test** the following code, but have no idea about it.

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import db from './db';

async function uploadUserInfo(userID: number) {
const user = db.findByPk(userID);
    if(!user) throw new Error('User not Found')
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
await S3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'users',
    Key:userID,
    Body: JSON.stringify(user.get())
})
    
}
```

As far as I understand the code, it is an asynchronous function to upload user information, validate it, and uses a new instance of a AWS Class to put the userId into the database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, the function won't run as it has what appears to be an undeclared variable (`order`).  So you can probably test that and return it to the dev as 'broken'.

It's testable assuming your test environment knows the database content, and that the AWS credentials are correct (and presumably not a live/production instance).  If this is true, then you can supply known userID values and check that the AWS bucket receives the data.

The function is not well implemented in that its dependencies (db and AWS) are not injectable, and therefore they cannot easily be substituted with mock implementations for testing purposes.

Some testing tools might allow you to intercept the module loading so that you can provide a mock db and AWS implementation, and that would allow you to check that the relevant calls are made with the correct data, based on the userID parameter.

If you have the ability to modify the function so that it is more testible, then if you add the db and AWS instance as parameters, then you can supply mocks, and use those to validate the internal implementation.

Comment: `order` variable was wrongly named, it should have been `user`. As far as I understood, should I discuss about the black-box and white-box testing? Different cases on how function would react to different input? Thank for the other explanation though.

Comment: You probably need to make a list of ways in which it could fail, and see which ones are under your control in a test environment.  Like can you induce a failure in AWS.  As written, the function either silently succeeds (no return value), or throws an error in the case of DB failure, and maybe in the case of AWS putObject failure (check the docs).  The problem with using external resources in tests is that they generally run slower, and are brittle due to external failures you can't control.  Mocking internals can make brittle tests due to expecting certain implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to test it by inputing different values of `UserID`. Since I assume no other part of code has been given, you need to test it with varied input values only, and play around with the Error handling

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).